# symfony2 passing form getdata to another action

Tags: symfony

i'm new to symfony, and don't know how to use a variable of one action in another one.
can someone give me a detailled solution?
in the first action, i retrieve selected values of a form in the $manifestations variable.

## the form

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'ProtoBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required'=>false
            ));
}  


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName() {
    return 'protobundle_manifestations';
}
}
```

## controller

```
public function indexAction{
    //....
    $form = $this->createForm(new ManifSearchType(), $entity);
    $manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();
    //....
    $response1 = $this->render('ProtoBundle:Invite:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'manifestations' => $manifestations,

    return $response1;
}
```

## index.html.twig file

```
{% block body %}
//....
<div id="resultats_affiches">
    {% include 'ProtoBundle:Invite:results.html.twig' with
        {   'entities' : entities,
            'manifestations' : manifestations,
        } 
    %}
</div>
//....
{% endblock %}
```

I want to use this $manifestations variable in another action that exports the retrieved data in a csv file:

```
/**
 * @Route("/export/{manifestations}", name="invite_export")
 */
public function exportCsvAction($manifestations) {

    $invites = $repository->searchInviteByManif($manifestations);

    $response = $this->render('ProtoBundle:Invite:export.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $invites));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $csvfile = $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    return $csvfile;
}
```

then being able to click on a link that redirect to this 2nd action, to exports the file

## results.html.twig file

```
<a href="{{ path('invite_export', { 'manifestations': manifestations }) }}"><img height="40px" width="40px" src={{ asset('bundles/images/imprimante-icone-8350-96.png') }} ></a>
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your should provide the `$manifestations` variable to your `exportCsvAction()` controller in order to do this. You can do that by passing it to the `path()` twig function in your template. In the action that renders the template that produces the link you provided, pass in the manifestations data and do something like the following:

```
<a href="{{ path('invite_export', { 'id': manifestation.id }) }}"><img height="40px" width="40px" src={{ asset('bundles/images/imprimante-icone-8350-96.png') }} ></a>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, i've modified the first action to pass the data in the twig file, you can see it in the top. and added this path in the index.html.twig file: <a {{ path('invite_export', { 'libelle': manifestations.libelle }) }}>..</a>. my question is how the second action is going to regognize this path, do i have to add it in its route as well, like export/{manifestation}or somewhere else: exportCsvAction($manifestations)? can you enlighten me on this point?

Comment: Yes. Add it to the route and action as you described. It's just like any other route with parameters.

Comment: after clicking on the link <a href="{{ path('invite_export', { 'manifestations': manifestations }) }}">, i get this error message: The requested URL /proto/web/app_dev.php/invite/export/Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@0000000050e2e36e000000007baa7b81 was not found on this server. do you have an idea on how to fix this? i've updated the question code on the top. is there something wrong in it?

Comment: Symfony can't generate the url because your are passing it a collection of objects rather than a literal. Try passing, for example, an id of a single manifestation.

Answer (score 0):

i confirm the response @johnny , the other solution is by using session to stock your variable but it's not a nice solution

Comment: thanks for reply. after clicking on the link <a href="{{ path('invite_export', { 'manifestations': manifestations }) }}">, i get this error message: The requested URL /proto/web/app_dev.php/invite/export/Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection‌​@0000000050e2e36e000000007baa7b81 was not found on this server. do you have an idea on how to fix this? i've updated the question code on the top. could you check and tell me if there's something wrong in it?